# Get changed data after execute bulk

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have recently started using the bulk operation to perform massive upgrades. I wanted to know what documents have been modified according to the query provided, to later obtain some data from the documents. When you run "bulk.getOperations();" I do not return only the changed documents, but all the queries executed and all the documents.

Is there any way to get the documents changed? The problem with running individual updates is that they are several million records running and the server is triggered in memory and CPU consumption, currently executing bulk in groups of 1000 querys, which I divide before. I only get the idea of getting the date before executing the bulk, use a date field with the current date in the update and once finished, look for the documents larger than that date.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Best regards

Comment: The only output available is the [`BulkWriteResult`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/BulkWriteResult.html). Whilst this contains more detail for "upsertedIds", which can even be matched back to the "index" of the batch of operations that was sent in the request, the information on `nMatched` and `nModified` are simply "numbers". There is nothing to indicate "which" documents were modified, nor can there be since operations can be `updateOne, updateMany, removeOne, removeMany` that would effect this number, and inherently several of these apply to more than one document.

Comment: Also `replaceOne` ( ran out of space ). If you are looking for *"retrieving the actual document after modification"* then that is what the `findAnd***()` series of methods are for. But of course, these are actually the antithesis of "bulk". So for true "bulk" writes, the least thing on your mind should be to think about *"which documents got updated"*. You should simply accept they were *"The ones that matched the conditions I sent in the query"* and move on with it.